# Plotting a function in scilab

Tags: scilab

can you help me, I 'm trying to plot the function y=1/x in scilab,
the graph that throws me is incorrect

```
x = [1:1:10]';
y = 1./x;
plot(x,y)
```

and throws me these results

y=

```
0.0025974  
0.0051948  
0.0077922  
0.0103896  
0.0129870  
0.0155844  
0.0181818  
0.0207792  
0.0233766  
0.0259740
```

and this result is wrong , as would be the code ,
Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write

```
y = 1 ./ x;
```

instead of

```
y = 1./x;
```

---

From the [documentation](https://help.scilab.org/doc/5.3.3/en_US/slash.html) *(emphasis is mine)*:

> a ./ b is the matrix with entries a(i,j)/ b(i,j). If b is scalar (1x1 matrix) this operation is the same as a./b*ones(a). (Same convention if a is a scalar).
>
> Remark that **123./b is interpreted as (123.)/b**. In this cases dot is part of the number not of the operator.

Comment: Thanks for the help